# Unity3d Keep moving an object smoothly

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, move

There are lots of similar question in the web.

But all that I've searched are to move from A position to B position.

I can do this with Lerf, MoveTowards and etc.

Anyways, I have a speed value and want to keep moving a gameObject.

Here's my code.

```
float m_fSpeed = 0.1f;

void Update()
{
   transform.Translate(Vector3.right * m_fSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
}
```

I am testing a cube object and with the code the cube doesn't move smoothly as I expected.

Is there another way to move gameobject?

Comment: Define "smoothly". You can, and probably should, use the FixedUpdate method instead and apply m_fSpeed (hungarian notation is soooo 90s) without multiplying with deltaTime.

Comment: I changed to FixedUpdate and do like m_fspeed * Time.FixedTime.
It's totally fast LOL. and when I used Time.FixedDeltaTime, the object didn't move smoothly. I should find another way to do.

Comment: If it's too fast reduce m_fSpeed. FixedUpdate runs multiple times per frame hence the speed increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use physics for that. Attach a rigidbody and set `rigidbody.velocity=Vector3.right*m_fSpeed`.

Comment: It won't get any smoother. You've probably got framerate issues.

Comment: Ya, I think so too. :)

Comment: Then they're not because of object movement.